# Configure typescript to output imports with extensions, ex: `from './file.js``

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, node-modules

Using node 14.x I would like to switch my project to full ES Modules, as it's now supported.
So I enabled on package.json `"type": "module"`

and my `tsconfig.json` looks like that:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2020"
  }
}
```

But the output files have unspecified extension in imports, it's instead **REQUIRED** for node 14.x to specify full file ext

For example:

```js
import { ENV, redisConfig } from './config';
```

should instead be:

```js
import { ENV, redisConfig } from './config.js';
```

Comment: How does the import look like in the TypeScript file?

Comment: on typescript it's `import { ENV, redisConfig } from './config';` but the file is named "config.ts"

Answer (score 1):

TS won't handle that for you, but you can run Node with the node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node parameter.
[Source](https://github.com/dandv/typescript-modern-project#import-your-own-modules-without-specifying-an-extension)

Unfortunately it seems that [TS isn't going to support](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-754941937) adding extension to the end of the import, since apparently [it's not as simple as adding `.js` to the end of the import](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-703190339).